# adding authorizers and cors to CloudFormation json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have this resource:

```
"MyUserAuthorizer": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "MyProject::MyProject.Functions::UserAuthorizer",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "Description": "authorizer",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaFullAccess"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to add an AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer resource that will use this MyUserAuthorizer lambda.
I tried this:

```
"Auth": {
  "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
  "Properties" : {
      "AuthorizerCredentials" : null,
      "AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds" : 300,
       "IdentitySource": "method.request.header.Authorization",
      "Name" : "Auth",
      "Type" : "TOKEN"
    }
  }
```

,
How do I connect it to the lambda authorizer function?
All I have in the json is other lambda functions. Should I have api gateway definitions?
How do I add CORS support for all the lambda functions?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your function with the authorizer:

```
            MYRestApiAuthorizer:
            Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
            Properties:
                RestApiId: !Ref HelloCORSRestApi
                Name: "MyAuthorizer"
                Type: TOKEN
                IdentitySource: "method.request.header.Authorization"
                AuthorizerUri: !GetAtt MyUserAuthorizer.Arn
```

To Enable CORS:

```
    .....
    
    HelloCORSRestApiResource:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
        Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref HelloCORSRestApi
        ParentId: !GetAtt 
            - HelloCORSRestApi
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: hello


    HelloCORSRestApiRequestGET:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
        Properties:
        AuthorizationType: CUSTOM
        AuthorizerId: !MYRestApiAuthorizer
        HttpMethod: GET
        Integration:
            Type: AWS
            IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
            Uri: ....
            IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
                ResponseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"          

        ResourceId: !Ref HelloCORSRestApiResource
        RestApiId: !Ref HelloCORSRestApi
        MethodResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
```

.....

```
    OptionsMethod:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
        Properties:
            AuthorizationType: NONE
            RestApiId: !Ref HelloCORSRestApi
            ResourceId: !Ref: HelloCORSRestApiResource
            HttpMethod: OPTIONS
            Integration:
            IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
                ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'<UPDATE_HTTP_METHODS_HERE>'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                ResponseTemplates:
                application/json: ''
            PassthroughBehavior: when_no_match
            RequestTemplates:
                application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
            Type: MOCK
            MethodResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
            ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: false
```

There is more to it if you wanna check [here](https://github.com/seraphjiang/aws-cors-cloudformation)

Comment: you can convert json to yaml and vice versa using [this](https://www.json2yaml.com/)
there is another tool from aws called [cfn-flip](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly I'm supposed to do. I have a lot of 'AWS::Serverless::Function' definitions. Should I have a 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method' also for each one of them?

Comment: yes, you need to pass the authorizer settings in the [AWS::ApiGateway::Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html) where you want the authorization.